# What is return value optimization?

Tags: c++

Reading through the answer for [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/1135954), a comment says

> This should be `split(s, delim, elems); return elems;`, to enable return value optimization.

The relevant piece of code is

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

Line 3 and 4 were earlier

```
 return split(s, delim, elems);
```

Can you please explain what benefit do we get by splitting that line of code?

Comment: Look it up on cppreference.com